# What's the name of these graphic elements at the end of an article?

Tags: typography, terminology, typesetting, paragraph, newspaper

It's a graphic element used in magazines and newspapers at the end of an article, to let the reader know the text ends in that page. It can be the magazine logo, or a variant of it, or just an abstract shape.

[image: end of an article text]

Answer (score 10):

I think it is simply called an *end mark*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_mark

Answer (score 8):

As the [tombstone character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography)) ∎ has been used in this capacity very regularly, I have seen these end marks referred to by that name.

Comment: Support for this answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.

Comment: @ideogram Thanks, included one of those links in the answer.